# Toggle up/down icons while toggling a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is driving me nuts, not sure why but I can't get the DIV to display. Also there is and icon, that doesn't trigger correctly, see here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14axwg13/)

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="cert-specify1" name="standard-specify"> 
<label class="label-inline toggle-survey-specify" for="cert-specify1"><span></span>Specify Survey(s)</label>

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="display: none;"></span>
        <div class="survey-specify hidden-div">
            <select  multiple="multiple">
                <option>Prior Survey - 1</option>
                <option>Prior Survey - 2</option>
                <option>Prior Survey - 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle-survey-specify').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.survey-specify').toggleClass('hidden-div');
        $(this).next('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a small mistake by using `.next()`, since it is not the next element. By using `.parent()` and `.find()`/`.children()` you'll be able to solve this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggle-survey-specify').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.survey-specify').toggleClass('hidden-div');
        $(this).next('span').slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could use `.next().next().next()`

Added to that, you've used `slideToggle(0)`, which says it should animate in 0 seconds. A simple `toggle()` should do.

As for the icon that isn't working, you don't animate the other icon to show.

I've altered your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14axwg13/1/). Let me know if you've got any follow up questions.

Comment: That gets me 1/2 there, now for the icons not toggling correctly.

Comment: Read that part later. Added it for you now.